# Changing all urls on page loading

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Let's suppose I have a page in which I'd like to append a parameter (for example `?name=fc`) to each and every url (also images etc.).

I'm trying to do this with greasemonkey using a regex, but it doesn't seem to work (i.e., the links on the page don't change).

Here is my code

```
var txt = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var exp = "/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig" ;
document.documentElement.innerHTML =( txt.replace(exp, "$1?name=fc"));
```

My JavaScript knowledge is almost zero, so bear with me.

So the question is, what's wrong with that JavaScript?

Comment: Try also `var txt = document.body.innerHTML;` The regexp might be wrong too, it's cerrain wrong because it would also replace any string in txt written as link even if it's not a real link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//loop 1: change links <a href="..."
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; ++i)
   links[i].href = links[i].href + "?name=fc";

//loop 2: change images <img src="..."
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; ++i)
   imgs[i].href = imgs[i].href + "?name=fc";

//loop 3: change image maps <area href="..."
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
for(var i = 0, len = areas.length; i < len; ++i)
   areas[i].href = areas[i].href + "?name=fc";
```

As specified by [Mike Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425059/changing-all-urls-on-page-loading/5425107#5425107) in the other answer in place of `loop 1 and 3` you could write one single loop using his answer, but still you need the `loop 2` for images' `src`s

Comment: I chose the other one just because it's shorter and I need to carry it on my cell phone :-/

Comment: r u just storing it on your phone?

Comment: @Erik we do not have internet access at work (for now) so I mailed it to myself and copied by hand from the phone screen. Ah... technolgy... -_-'

Comment: @Federico Culloca: the other one wont't replace urls in images as you asked `(also images etc.)` :)

Comment: @Federico Culloca: edited a bit to include also the area (the image map Matt McDonald talked about in the comment to Mike Lewis answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
 document.links[i].href += "?name=fc"
}
```

You should just use the [document.links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) attribute. This will append "?name=fc" to all links (a's and img's etc).

Comment: Bingo. Using `document.links` will touch both anchor and area (image map) tags that have `href` attributes.